# Import CSV to Azure PostgreSQL withough Superuser

Tags: azure-postgresql

I'm trying to upload a CSV file into Azure Postgresql. However when I run the command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
```

However, Azure Postgresql doesn't allow users to be super users. How can I import the file?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `\copy` command available in `psql`? I'm fairly sure it allows reading/ writing files local to the client and doesn't require you to be a superuser. See https://codeburst.io/two-handy-examples-of-the-psql-copy-meta-command-2feaefd5dd90